# HttpClient giving 404 request on create-react-app

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-core, get

I'm working with some code in asp.net core and part of it gets the url, and using HttpClient, using GetAsync method to do a get request. In the constructor, I have
 `private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();`
and in another method, the `_client` gets used to do the get request, for example,

```
private async Task<string> GetContent(string url){
 var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
}
```

I always get a 404 not found error when I use localhost:3000 or http://localhost:3000 from my create-react-app project. How can I get it to work? It works for other sites like google. It even works for the localhost url that swagger is using.

Comment: what is in `url`?

Comment: And what happens if you manually navigate to `url` in your browser?

Comment: @DanielA.White the url to get passed in

Comment: @ronaldreagan Yes, we understand that. Daniel is asking you what is the *value* of `url`.

Comment: @mason when I go to the url, i get the component depending on what route I am on. I'm using react router in the project

Comment: @mason the value is "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: Try it with a protocol, as in `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @mason I did try that, i tried it with and without http and i tried using my ip and none works